# Is it possible to pass through url a non-ASCII value? Or is there some other mistake here that I'm not seeing?

Tags: python, utf-8, jinja2

From this block of code:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        template_values = {"given_sentence":'put a sentence here'}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
        nb = naivebayes(getfeatures)
        sampletrain(nb)
        given_sentence = self.request.get("given_sentence").encode('utf-8')
      #  given_sentence = self.request.get("given_sentence")
        spam_result = nb.classify(given_sentence)
        submit_button = self.request.get("submit_button")
        if submit_button:
            self.redirect('/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 262, in post
    self.redirect('/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 608, in redirect
    response=self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1767, in redirect
    uri = str(urlparse.urljoin(request.url, uri))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 82: ordinal not in range(128)
INFO     2012-08-16 20:02:52,229 dev_appserver.py:2952] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2012-08-16 20:05:06,858 py_zipimport.py:148] zipimporter('C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg', '')
ERROR    2012-08-16 20:05:08,230 webapp2.py:1553] 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 262, in post
    self.redirect('/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When the value of `given_sentence` is something like this: `productos farmacéuticos comprar ahora`.

I my python code is in utf-8. I also put on my templates (in the `<head>` tag) this line: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`.

The problem seens to be in passing a non-ASCII sentence through the url. If I try this ("productos comprar ahora"), it's ok:

```
http://localhost:8084/test_result?spam_result=good&given_sentence=productos%20comprar%20ahora
```

But If I try this: "productos farmacéuticos comprar ahora" I got the above error. Isn't it possible to pass through url a non-ASCII value? Or is there some other mistake here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: probably urlencode that sucker!

Comment: You should read up on `urllib`, `urllib2`, and `urlencode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic Python encoding issue. You are trying to put a non-ASCII string into an ASCII one. Use unicode instead (note the `u`):

```
self.redirect(u'/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))
```

(and drop the `encode` call on getting given_sentence).

Comment: Unless he has an explicit encoding directive in his file, or is setting the default python encoding some other way, he's probably going to need to do a `decode('utf-8')` on his source string first.  His example and his stack trace and further explanation do not match up (example code appears non-functional regardless of encoding to me).

Comment: I don't see why. AFAIK webapp2 (actually WebOb, which deals with the request stuff) decodes all request params to unicode before they reach the handler. As long as his URL string is also unicode, there's no reason to encode to bytes at all.

Comment: Ahh, I see now.  I was thinking his strings were sourcing from outside his code in reality (the example he gave is a pretty odd and specific string to be hard coding to me), but if they are hardcoded directly, I see you are right.

Comment: Thanks more one time, @DanielRoseman. You help me a lot - again!

Comment: @DanielRoseman, but if I drop the `encode`call, I got this error: `uri = str(urlparse.urljoin(request.url, uri))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 103: ordinal not in range(128)` and if I don't, I got this other error: `line 263, in post
    self.redirect(u'/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it possible to pass through url a non-ASCII value?

No, it's not. The problem here isn't Python, but the URL/URI specification [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (see sections 2.0-2.3).

A URL can only contain characters from a restricted subset of ASCII.

But there is a way to pass any arbitrary byte stream as part of a URL: percent encoding (section 2.4). So, if you've got the UTF-8 byte string "farmac\xc3\xa9uticos" you can send that as "farmac%C3%A9uticos".

If you use urllib.urlencode to generate your query string out of a dict, instead of trying to do it manually, it'll take care of this for you.

But what if you've got the Unicode string "farmacéuticos"? Well, you'll have to encode that into UTF-8, or some other byte string encoding, so you can percent-encode it and pass it through a URL. And the server on the other side has to know that it's getting UTF-8 (after URL decoding) so it can reconstruct your Unicode string.